# Ruby where array is not empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this_id is a string, that is an array, the_other is a boolean (from before I learned to default: false).

I do not know the format a search where the arrays('that') are not empty, [], i.e., have at least one thing in it.  Thanks!

```
This.where("this_id = ? and that = ? and the_other IS NOT NULL", "#{@this.id}", ...NOT_EMPTY?)
```

Comment: is an empty array NULL?

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL and an array column for `that`?

Comment: Yes and yes thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PostgreSQL array documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html), To compare with array type column you can use `'{}'`, so you can write your query like this

```
This.where("this_id = ? and that != '{}' and the_other IS NOT NULL", "#{@this.id}")
```

This should return the required rows.

Comment: Ok thanks!   ... so ruby array [ ] and postres array { }.    whats a postgres hash, [ ] ?

Comment: there is no hash type in postgresSQL, but there is a json type or hstore. here are documentation links for both. 

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-hstore/

Comment: my pleasure. :)